# Check if WM_PARENTNOTIFY is deprecated API?

Tags: winapi

According to docs `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` seems to be deprecated, this sounds unusual but if this is the case then what API does replace it?

[WM_PARENTNOTIFY message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms632638(v=vs.85))

Comment: What text on that page possibly makes you think it is deprecated? The requirements are simply (as stated) minimum versions. Things MS is trying to remove from the API are marked extremely clearly, and even then they don't always succeed.

Comment: I see, because I couldn't find up to date link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not deprecated, you just happen to hit a bit outdated link.
The most recent I believe is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify).

Comment: I found only 2 results in search engine, both leading to link I posted, that made me confused.

Comment: Finding the most recent docs from Microsoft might sometimes be a big challenge.

Comment: @Jovibor You should have tried it when the docs were Petzold and the .hlp file that came with the compiler and that's all you had.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have gotten confused by the disclaimer on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms632638(v=vs.85)) entry. There are two parts to it:

> We're no longer updating this content regularly.

This refers to the documentation itself. It got frozen at some point, when Microsoft decided to change their documentation site for the *n*-th time (with *n* > 3). Though it's probably the second part that had you confused:

> Check the [Microsoft Product Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products) for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.

Since this documentation no longer receives updates, there's no promise made as to whether the content still applies. It could (and generally is) still accurate, but it could be wrong or outdated as well, and you would need to check elsewhere.

That elsewhere is here: [`WM_PARENTNOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify). It would certainly be nice to have the old documentation auto-redirect to the new content (and sometimes this works, too, easily identifiable by a query string that contains the `redirectedfrom=MSDN` parameter). If in doubt you can identify up-to-date documentation by an [Edit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify.md) link at the top right corner.

Comment: Indeed , sometimes it's hard to find up to date docs when we stumble upon outdated pages.